# Android, How to add Google map options from XML layout?

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a fragment that holds a MapView. I have added this view in XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    map:uiCompass="true"
    android:background="#00000000" />
```

And I've linked it to my code like this:

```
public class HotSpotsFragment extends MainFragment implements LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "HotSpotsFragment";
    private Context context;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // create view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hot_spots, container, false);

        // Getting context
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        // Make sure user's device supports Google play services
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Google play service is not available.");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.string.hot_spots_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Google play service is available.");

        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        googleMap = ((MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();
        if(googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.string.hot_spots_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "View created");

        return view;
    }
.
.
.
}
```

I want to add to add options to my map view. Based on what has been mentioned on [GoogleMapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions), "These options can be used when adding a map to your application programmatically (as opposed to via XML). If you are using a MapFragment, you can pass these options in using the static factory method newInstance(GoogleMapOptions). If you are using a MapView, you can pass these options in using the constructor MapView(Context, GoogleMapOptions)." and finally my case,"**If you add a map using XML, then you can apply these options using custom XML tags.**"

I didn't find any sample to show how to add options through XML. I want to add zOrderOnTop="true" into my XML code.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi Hesam! I am not able to display MapView if i use the below code  **mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        googleMap = ((MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView)).getMap();**

Comment: But, when i specify **mapView.onResume();** after **mapView.onCreate(savedInstance)** it is working What am i doing wrong? Is it possible to display map without specifying **onResume()** ? Plz help me

Comment: I guess you have not implemented other required method. That's why it happens. You no need to write "mapView.onResume();" in onCreateView() method. Make sure you have following methods after onCreateView():

Comment: *Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(mapView != null)
            mapView.onResume();
    }

    *Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if(mapView != null)
            mapView.onPause();
    }

    *Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if(mapView != null)
            mapView.onDestroy();
    }

Comment: *Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if(mapView != null)
            mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    *Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        if(mapView != null)
            mapView.onLowMemory();

        super.onLowMemory();
    }

Comment: please replace * with @. I couldn't user that because editor said not more than 1 @ is allowed :(

Comment: Hi Hesam Thank's a lot for your answer. I was able to display map. But  when i navigate to another activity/fragment and come back then it is not saving the previous state of map. The map is being reloaded again. Plz help me ... i dont want the map to reload again ...

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14114428/513413 I think it solves your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was as easy as

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    map:uiCompass="true"
    map:zOrderOnTop="true"
    map:uiZoomControls="true"
    android:background="#00000000" />
```

However new problem is adding `map:zOrderOnTop="true"` will remove overlay objects such as ZoomIn/ZoomOut from screen :(
For more info refer to [this link](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&groupby=&sort=&id=4812).