# Mapview in google-api-v2 with rounded corners in android

Tags: android, rounded-corners, mapfragment

I am writing an app in android using MapFragment, so i want that the corners of the mapview rounded i create a shape in a xml file and set the shape as a background of the map but i didn't got the result i want.
 the corners of the map are not rounded but the background is and actually that's what my code do, so can anyone give me an issue to have a rounded corner mapview, any idea.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this question I asked on exactly the same topic:

[Is there a way to implement rounded corners to a Mapfragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469208/is-there-a-way-to-implement-rounded-corners-to-a-mapfragment)

basically you need to create an appropriate 9-patch image and apply it over them map using another layout with `FrameLayout`.

Comment: i will try this and let you know the results

Comment: You can certainly see from my question that it works and the steps are presented to you as well. So let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: I have posted an anser explaining the steps i followed to create a rounded corner map. i hope that will be helpfull, thanks.

Comment: Great @Adil, that looks like an interesting way.

Comment: thanks @Emil Adz, if you see we can apply this to any view we want like an image or something else, all that we need is to pass the view that we want its corner rounded as a parameter to the constructer RoundedCornerMap. i want now to play with the width and the height to have some space in the screen so i can add something else, i'm changing the height in the xml file but nothing happen.

Answer (score 2):

I've made some research and i found an issue. Well i've created a view that extend 
LinearLayout (or framelayout) this view is like that

```
public class RoundedCornerMap extends LinearLayout{

Bitmap windowFrame;
//this constructer is needed by a tool in explipse to render the layout, you can not define it
public RoundedCornerMap(Context context, AttributeSet attr){
    super(context, attr);
}
//this 
public RoundedCornerMap(Context context, AttributeSet attr, View view) {
    super(context, attr);
    init(view);
}

private void init(View view) {

    view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    view.setClickable(true);
    addView(view);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

    if(windowFrame==null)
        createWindowFrame();// Lazy creation of the window frame, this is needed as we don't know the width & height of the screen until draw time

    canvas.drawBitmap(windowFrame, 0, 0, null);
}

private void createWindowFrame() {

    windowFrame= Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);// Create a new image we will draw over the map
    Canvas osCanvas = new Canvas(windowFrame);// Create a    canvas to draw onto the new image

    RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    RectF innerRectangle = new RectF(10, 10, getWidth()-10, getHeight()-10);

    float radiusCorner = getWidth()/18f;// The angle of your corners

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);// Anti alias allows for smooth corners
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(Color.BLACK));// This is the color of your activity background
    osCanvas.drawRect(outerRectangle, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);// An obvious color to help debugging
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));// A out B http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Alpha_compositing.svg
    osCanvas.drawRoundRect(innerRectangle, radiusCorner, radiusCorner, paint);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    windowFrame=null;// If the layout changes null our frame so it can be recreated with the new width and height
}

}
```

The onCreate method of the Fragment extending the Mapfragment will be like that:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.layout.rounded_corner_map);
    AttributeSet attr = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);


    View view=new RoundedCornerMap(myActivity, attr, super.onCreateView(inflater, container, null));
    //ignore about this line below i just want to set a shape to the view
    //view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.map_shape);
    return view;
}
```

and we need to difine the xml file rounded_corner_map like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.map.RoundedCornerMap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

I hope that this will help you.

Comment: this seems strictly worse than the 9 patch solution - if you're just drawing black corners in, why not use a background 9 patch, which seems made for a scenario just like this one?

Answer (score -1):

Put your map in any layout like LinearLayout/RelativeLayout or any layout and set that shape style to Layout as background.

My shape file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <stroke android:color="#aa6632"/>
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

My layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/test">
    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can use `FrameLayout` also instead of `LinearLayout`

Comment: from my experience this wont work, did you try this implementation? can you supply the shape style code and layout code that worked for you?

Comment: i tried your code the map is not shown, and the corner are not rounded, instead the corners of the linearlayout are rounded that's what i got in my first attempt, but thanks.