# Using a Layout to Make Rounded Corners affect on image

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have some `ImageView's` and it seems like too much trouble to round the corners by using an `ImageLoader` or similar technique.

Can I just simply make a `LinearLayout` to cover the image? (or set the Image as its background?)  For example, if the layout had rounded corners, would it hide the portion of the image beneath to create a rounded corner affect?

I have been trying to play with this (specifically using image as background) and can't seem to hide the image's corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, with FrameLayout or RelativeLayout you can easily stack a second layer on top of you imageview like:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/myrealimage" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/my_roundedcorner_overlay"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/myoverlaywithroundedcornersandtransparentcenter" />
</FrameLayout>
```

however, be warned this causes overdraw and makes your layout more complex.

You could also set the real image as a background to you ImageView and the overlay as the ImageViews src, however don't set a padding in this case (also loading images from the web with a library probably won't work anymore)

Cleanest solution is to create a custom widget extending ImageView and override its onDraw method, paint to the canvas using a bitmapshader, similar to http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/ pretty much the same, but do it once and reuse as often as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same problem, Only I wanted  to create a Google Map with rounded corners, check this 
question:

[Is there a way to implement rounded corners to a Mapfragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469208/is-there-a-way-to-implement-rounded-corners-to-a-mapfragment)

The trick is to create a `FrameLayout` and in it place you content and on top of it place another layout with a `9-patch` image background that has rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) you can round the corners of the the image instead.

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()            
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer())
        .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, imageView, options);
```