# how to display android mapfragment view rounded shape

Tags: google-maps, android-mapview, android, supportmapfragment

i have to show map view in rounded shape , is it posible to show  android map view with rounded shape.
I have tried to applying fragment layout gadient but after  map loading is showing rectange view.
any guidence for to make android rounded mapview

Comment: Show your source code?

Comment: paha i have refered this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start, and applyied gadient for  map view backgroung  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#ffffFF"
        android:startColor="#FFFFff" />

</shape>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it possible. Cover the `MapFragment` with another layout, and set for this layout a **9-patch** background, that will cover it the way you want, take a look at this question I asked on the same topic not long ago:

[Is there a way to implement rounded corners to a Mapfragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469208/is-there-a-way-to-implement-rounded-corners-to-a-mapfragment)

Answer (score 1):

You can use shapes in layer-list
[image]
here is the shape_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_circle_rect"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shape_circle_oval"/>
</layer-list>
```

shape_circle_rect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:width="50dp" android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <padding
            android:left="-50dp"
            android:top="-50dp"
            android:right="-50dp"
            android:bottom="-50dp"/>
</shape>
```

shape_circle_oval.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval" >
    <stroke android:color="#ffffff" android:width="100dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

and Custom Map Fragment

```
    public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment{
    //...
    //Some methods, set up map and etc.
    //...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
        View mapView = super.onCreateView(inflater, viewGroup, bundle);
        RelativeLayout view = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        view.addView(mapView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        FrameLayout frameLayout=new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        frameLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_circle);
        view.addView(frameLayout);
        return view;
    }
    //...
    //...
 }
```