# Rounded corner google map android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to implement google map in a rounded corner view? I tried using custom rounded corner viewgroup but the map is not visible (google is written on bottom right corner). Is there any possible way to implement this?

Comment: Recently I required this functionality, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469208/is-there-a-way-to-implement-rounded-corners-to-a-mapfragment helped me.

Comment: My view is framed over another views and reused in different activities ..So cannot maintain the background color