# how to make rounded corners for FragmentContainerView in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a fragment container view that changes the fragment based on the selection in a spinner. I want the fragments to have rounded corners. I believe adding rounded corners to fragmentContainerView will do what I need? How can I do this? I tried adding a drawable resource file(shape) to background but it didn't work.

My drawable resource file

[image: My drawable.xml file]

My activity.xml code

[image: My activity.xml code]

The way it still shows in the app. The red part is the FragmentContainerView

[image: The way it still shows in the app]

Answer (score 0):

CustomerRegisterFragment have it‘s own background which will cover the FragmentContainerView background you set.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in order for the drawable resource file to take effect, it must contain the tag `<solid>` with a color attribute. Then it displays as required

Comment: dublicated question  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45970831/2695939

Answer (score 0):

```
you can wrap with CardView like this:

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fcvMap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).